# Fill surface with outline in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

**Desired outcome:**

- Draw two identical toolbars next to each other:

  - Color = lightgrey
  - Outline = black

**Actual outcome:**

- Left hand toolbar is:

  - Color = lightgrey
  - Outline = black
- Right hand toolbar is:

  - Color = black
  - Outline = black

**Question:** How do I achieve my desired outcome?

**My code:**

```
import pygame
import random
from os import path
WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 30
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
LIGHTGREY = (220, 220, 220)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("tests")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def fill_woutline(surface, fill_color, outline_color, rect, border=1):
    surface.fill(outline_color, rect)
    surface.fill(fill_color, rect.inflate(-border, -border))

class Bar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, centerx, y, width, height, fill_color, outline_color, border=1):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = centerx
        self.rect.y = y
        fill_woutline(self.image, fill_color, outline_color, self.rect, border)

all_bars = pygame.sprite.Group()
toolbar = Bar(25, 0, 50, 360, LIGHTGREY, BLACK, 2)
toolbar2 = Bar(100, 0, 50, 360, LIGHTGREY, BLACK, 2)
all_bars.add(toolbar, toolbar2)

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_bars.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Try debug your program by printing out the values for `outline_color` and `fill_color` in the `fill_woutline` function.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer I did and it showed the right values, both times (220, 220, 220) (0,0,0)

Comment: I tried to debug the program and I have found that the problem is the use of the `inflate` method. I still have not found a satisfactory method to draw the rectangles how you want but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer thanks, i was thinking the same, but i haven't figured out why yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the [`fill`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) method specifies the area of the surface that should be filled. If you blit/draw something on a surface then the topleft coords will always be (0, 0) independent of the surface's position on the screen. So because you pass the `rect`s with the world coords, you never draw anything on the second bar (the surface is filled with black by default).

To fix the `fill_woutline` function, you can just generate a new rect and deflate it.

```
def fill_woutline(surface, fill_color, outline_color, border=1):
    surface.fill(outline_color)
    surface.fill(fill_color, surface.get_rect().inflate(-border, -border))
```

Comment: Oh thanks, makes sense and that's also why it worked with the first, thank you